# Converter coluna para string onde tem valores nulos pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Como faço para converter uma coluna para string, toda vez que tento fazer

```
`df['COL1'] = ['COL1'].astype(str)`
```

onde tem nulos, o pandas converte para string "NAN", tem alguma forma de contorna esse problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você pode utilizar uma função lambda:

```
f = lambda x: '' if type(x) == np.nan else str(x)
```

dae é so aplicar a coluna

```
df['COL1'] = ['COL1'].apply(f)
```

caso não funcione. Você pode transformar em string primeiro e utilizar a função.

```
df['COL1'] = ['COL1'].astype(str)
f = lambda x: '' if x = 'NAN' else str(x)
```

caso queira substituir esses valores por outra coisas basta utilizar a função .fillnan().

```
df['COL1'] = ['COL1'].fillna(' ') #Ele ira colocar ' ' no lugar dos NAN.
```

Caso queira que os valores continuem como nan
utiliza a função:

```
f = lambda x: np.nan if x == np.nan else str(x)
df['COL1'] = ['COL1'].apply(f)
```

dependendo da verção do pandas isso pode ser problemático se der problema utilize:

```
f = lambda x: np.nan if str(x) == 'NAN' else x
df['COL1'] = ['COL1'].apply(f)
```

Espero ter ajudado

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Dessa forma coloca valores vazios, eu precisava que eles continuassem como nulos

Comment: Eu editei a resposta olha lá agora.

Comment: No caso essa funcionou `f = lambda x: np.nan if x == np.nan else str(x)
df['COL1'] = ['COL1'].apply(f)`